# What is this flat metal sieve that came with my pressure cooker for?

Tags: pressure-cooker

What is this tool used for and how to use it? It came with a pressure cooker I've bought...

[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The sieve-like item is a steamer insert, used to cook things that do not cook well if submerged in the comparatively large amount of water a pressure cooker needs to operate. The wire is a stand for this insert, to raise it above the waterline.

Unless you bought it used: Pressure cooker makers tend to give free books away with their pots, often a classic about a spanish guy called Manual. Good reading while watching a pressure cooker.

Comment: And how to use this stand? I didn't understand how this parts attach to each other

Comment: It doesn't attach - it is simply laid into the water, and the sieve ist stood on top, it cannot topple because the pot itself is too narrow.

Comment: You put the piece of wire in first, with the points downward, and it acts as a support for the sieve. I use mine for steaming potatoes. The bottom of the sieve should be just above the water level.

Comment: It's actually a stolen Scott Adams classic, but it fit :)

Comment: Unless given proof to the contrary, I would expect sarcasm to be more effective in making people think than dry "read your vegetables and eat your manuals" statements....

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Being sarcastic about it is less likely to encourage people to do that." https://xkcd.com/285/

Comment: @DavidRicherby This answer contains possibly the least insulting way to tell someone to "read the manual" that I have ever seen. It's downright delightful.

Answer (score 4):

If you just put the metal dish into the pressure cooker it has three dimples pointing down... so anything standing on top of it is not in contact with the physical bottom of the pan. The idea being that if you put some flat-bottom or concave bottom jars in they don't end up directly sitting on the pan's bottom. that could lead to hot spots under the jars... if you are bottling (canning in glass) stuff in the pressure cooker that could lead to burned contents or a cracked jar.

It's often called a trivet.

My mother's one didn't come with a wire stand... it just relied on the dimples to keep it off the bottom.

Comment: That said, before pressure canning anything in a pressure cooker of some description, talk to the spanish guy again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the trivet and sieve method to cook eggs.  Separation from the cooker bottom keeps them from bouncing in the boiling water and sometimes breaking open.